# TFS 2015 Tasks not appearing in one column (iteration board)

Tags: tfs, workflow, tfs-2015

I have a TFS Task Board (`Work` > `Backlogs` > `Iteration`) with four columns:

1. New
2. Active
3. Resolved
4. Closed

I have modified the workflow to allow `Tasks` to be moved through all four columns/states (they could not be `Resolved` before).

Unfortunately, any `task` that is moved to the `Resolved` state does not appear on the board. I can go find them and mark them as `Closed` (or any other state) at which point they reappear on the board.

Why are tasks in this one state not appearing on the board?

Things that may be useful

- TFS2015
- Column `Resolved` is mapped to state `Resolved` (in options)
- Changed behaviour was to allow tasks to enter the `Resolved` state
- I modified existing states and transitions rather than create new ones

The goal is to use the `Resolved` state as a "closed pending team consensus" column

**Update**

Screenshot to avoid confusion about what the problem is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

[image]

Export your WITD for Tasks from your dev machine via command line :

```
witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:"TeamProjectName" /n:Task /f:"C:\task.xml"
```

Edit this file and find the **WORKFLOW** section and add in your new state into **STATES** e.g:

```
<STATE value="Resolved" />
```

Next, in the **TRANSITIONS** section add in the required transitions and any logic associated with it e.g:

```
  <TRANSITION from="Active" to="Resolved">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Resolved from the backlog" />
          </REASONS>
        </TRANSITION>

 <TRANSITION from="Resolved" to="Closed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Closed from the backlog" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
```

Save the file and import it again:

```
witadmin importwitd /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs  /p:"TeamProjectName" /f:"C:\FileToExportTo.xml"
```

Then export Processconfig.xml add

```
<State type="InProgress" value="Resolved" />
```

under `<TaskBacklog category="Microsoft.TaskCategory" parent="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Tasks" singularName="Task" workItemCountLimit="1000">`

Import Processconfig.xml, close the browser and open it.

Everything should work as expected. Hope it's clearly.

---

On the task board it's only possible to add columns using **witadmin**, by **exporting the Task work item** and the **processconfig**, updating them (the XML manually) and importing them back into TFS.

In other words, you need to change two xml files, `Task.xml` and  `ProcessConfiguration.xml`.

Please make sure you have added that "Resolved" state to Task Work Item workflow in TFS 2015 successfully and customized your process.

Detail steps you could refer below useful links:

- [Adding a state to a Work Item workflow in TFS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362412/adding-a-state-to-a-work-item-workflow-in-tfs-2013)
- [TFS 2017 On Premise - Customizing Task Board Columns](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68bc61bb-a849-417b-aa2d-51bd84d38ba2/tfs-2017-on-premise-customizing-task-board-columns-etc?forum=tfsgeneral)
- [Adding additional states onto the Agile Task Board in TFS2012](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudiouk/2013/01/18/adding-additional-states-onto-the-agile-task-board-in-tfs2012/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the office now. I was referring to the "iteration" board that tasks appear on, not the Story Board. I originally downloaded the WIT XML and changed the states to include "Resolved" as a state. "Active" Tasks can be successfully transitioned to the "Resolved" state (drag/drop). The question is why they don't appear in the column when they are in the "Resolved" state.

Comment: @JeffereyCave Yeah, I was also talking about the iteration board. AKA task backlog-board. It works properly in my side. You have mentioned `downloaded the WIT XML and changed the states to include "Resolved" as a state. "Active" Tasks can be successfully transitioned to the "Resolved" state (drag/drop).` Did you also change the **TRANSITIONS**  of task work item type? Also make sure the state in task totally as same as **Resolved** column with same  caps lock. Test do not directly drag and change the status in task work item , check if it auto change  in resolved column. Details  see my update

Comment: So everything else had already been done. I made the changes to the `ProcessConfiguration.xml`, unfortunately the Task is still not visible in the Resolved column

Comment: Compare with the screenshot of yours and mine, there are something different in UI.( Missing a few white lines). I was wondering if related to your `ProcessConfiguration.xml`. You could try to directly use my  shared ProcessConfiguration file in OneDrive or refer to and compare difference with your own `ProcessConfiguration.xml`. Kindly check it through link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtdSbH1PdTBciy3XJhvXolJ69_74?e=XSPOTl

Comment: Hi  Jefferey, what's the result using my shared `ProcessConfiguration.xml`? Were you able to solve it? Besides, you could also try to create a new team project  or use another browser for test. This may help you narrow down the issue.